# getting unable to initialize module while installing imagick

Tags: apache, imagick, php-5.5

1)Imagick 3.3.0rc1 MagickGetImageAttribute entry point not found #92
2)followed the above link
3)[Followed this solutions](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/92)
4)now getting this error searched lot i think its issue with php version  and imagick version issue but how to fix it

thanks in advance

[image: getting following error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the latest version I tried downloading ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll from [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/). That one actually worked with the php_imagick.dll (Imagick for PHP 5.5.x) from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/.